# Thread is able to change ui if started from inside activity lifecycle methods. why?

Tags: android, multithreading, activity-lifecycle

I was testing this code to check if app crashes for changing ui component from background thread. but it didn't.

Here in the code added below. I started a new thread in `onCreate()` method of `MainActivity` and It should have crashed as per the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/define-runnable.html) which says

> In the class, the Runnable.run() method contains the code that's
>   executed. Usually, anything is allowable in a Runnable. Remember,
>   though, that the Runnable won't be running on the UI thread, so it
>   can't directly modify UI objects such as View objects.

So I was expecting it to crash. Which it didn't. See code -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  TextView txt;
  Thread thread;
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      txt.setText("bro");
    }
  };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
    thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
  }
}
```

While if i try changing ui while starting thread from `onClicklistener()` as below it does crash. which is expected.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  TextView txt;
  Thread thread;
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    txt.setText("bro");
  }
  };

  View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     thread.start();
    }
  };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
    thread = new Thread(runnable);
    txt.setOnClickListener(listener);
  }
}
```

Now, that the second code snippet crashes, which is expected and the first one doesn't.

Please explain why is this happening, as I'm creating a new worker thread each time but just at different places. Official docs reference will be appreciated.

Comment: what is `btn` and what is `txt` in the first snippet, you are linking with one and assigning text to another

Comment: From my understanding this crash wont happen prior to the view rendering. In the first case that you mentioned in the question the view property(text) has set in the view object and is waiting for the view to render it in the main thread  that is the view is not drawing with your thread at this point. But in the second case , the view is rendered and your call to setText will immediately executed with your background thread, then It will cause to crash.

Comment: @Krish i tried doing this in onResume method also. It worked there as well and onResume comes in the visible lifecycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason behind this behavior as pointed out by @krish in the comments on my question. The reason is that, the thread was able to make changes in the `TextView` object only till it was not visible on UI screen i.e not rendered. It is only after the view rendering, that any thread except the Main thread may not make changes to any UI components. I Tried using view observer to see if the view was rendered before the changes or not. which showed that changes were made before the view rendering.

Here is the code that i tried.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  TextView txt;
  Thread thread;
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      txt.setText("bro");
      Log.d("ThreadTest", "The Text was changed.");
    }
  };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
    thread = new Thread(runnable);

    txt.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Log.d("ThreadTest", "The TextView was rendered");
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    thread.start();
  }
}
```

Using the code above. You'll see in the output:

> The Text was changed.
>
> The TextView was rendered

Which means text was changed before view rendering. if you try to start thread to makes changes in onGlobalLayout method. App crashes as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The UI is not [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) see [processes-and-threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html), so you were just lucky you did not hit one of the many landmines waiting for you.
If you don't like relying on luck then:
You should be using:

```
runOnUiThread(runnable);
```

instead of:

```
thread = new Thread(runnable);
```

[AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) enables proper and easy use of the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jon, but I've already worked out the solution. 

I'm just looking for a proper reason here, as i couldn't find any.

please correct me if I'm misquoting you. From what i can understand from your answer here is that, By saying UI is not thread safe you mean that we might change UI from another thread but we cannot be sure if that will crash or not? and the first code snippet i used is case of may or may not crash condition.

Comment: @AkashRaghav Yes, you cannot be SURE it will crash, but what is the point ? The documentation tells you NOT to do something, but you want to do it anyway ? Why ?

Comment: I do not want to do it. I just want to know whats happening behind. The logic or reason of this behavior. coz, if something is documented, then it must work like what's specified. otherwise what is the point of documentation.